# I want to login to a Linux host as user "admin"/password="admin then sudo as root and change root password

Tags: perl

And all of this needs to be scripted in perl so this functionality is available to the 4 internal test hosts that i work with.

Comment: I guess this is >95% system administration. Serverfault might give better responses.

Comment: I want an angel to descend from the heavens carrying a suitcase full of diamonds.

Comment: Please clarify -- the linux box is set up right now such that the admin / admin login will work and your script's objective is to then change the root password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SSH::Expect